# Julia ccall() could not load library

Tags: julia

I am stuck with the problem of calling C library from Julia.

Here is the line:

```
test=ccall((:foo1,"DLL1"),Int32,(Int32, Int32),1,1)
```

DLL1.dll is in the same folder as main .jl file and pwd() returns this folder.
But Julia gives me the following error:

```
LoadError: error compiling anonymous: could not load library
```

Is there some better tutorials than official for ccall. Since it's not working even with libc.

Comment: Don't you need to include it's extension. "DLL1.dll"?
Also please link to what official tutorial you mean for `ccall`.
That could be a few things.

Comment: I've tried with extension and without. Here is official [link](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/)

Comment: It states that libraries loaded from platform specific paths meaning 'C:\....\system32' like paths. You may need to push your library's path to 'DL_LOAD_PATH' variable or directly call it with whole path 'pwd()/DLLNAME'.

Comment: So I've tried `ccall((:foo1,"pwd()/DLL1"),Int32,(Int32, Int32),1,1)` and still have the same error.

the .dll is in the pwd() folder

Comment: Well... I dont know why it's so... but I got the solution
`ccall(("foo1","pwd()/DLL1"),Int32,(Int32, Int32),1,1)`

however, following the official [info](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/), `(:function, "library")` or `("function", "library")` are both correct...

Comment: I mean `"$(pwd())/DLLNAME"` to be exact. I was just stating pseudo-code not julian code.

Comment: Also, this part of documentation is relevant too http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/libdl/

Comment: Often when you are doing this, you are going to want t be using BinDeps.jl anyway, to build the DLL. and doing the standard BinDeps `include` of the generated `deps.jl` file, solves this issue. Because it defines a checked filepath ()as a constant to your dependency lib. (Unfortunately bindeps doesn't have a ideal tutorial either)

Comment: I just double-checked and Julia 0.5 does automatically search `pwd` on Windows (10), so I think there must be something else going on here. You can test `dlopen("DLL1")` to potentially get more info.