# How to specify a relative library path in Julia ccall?

Tags: julia, method-call

to `ccall` a custom made library, I need to write down the library full path on the system:

```
j = ccall((:add3, "[FULL_PATH]/libmylib.so"), Float32, (Float32,), 2)
```

I am trying to use instead a relative path with:

```
j = ccall((:add3, "$(pwd())/libmylib.so"), Float32, (Float32,), 2)
```

but, while `"$(pwd())/libmylib.so"` returns the right path for the library, `ccall` with `pwd` returns a `TypeError: in ccall: first argument not a pointer or valid constant expression, expected Ptr, got Tuple{Symbol,String}`.

So, how to ccall a library that is in the same folder than the Julia script/current working directory ?

I am puzzled, as according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327599/julia-ccall-could-not-load-library) in Windows seems to work, even if the doc for `ccall` specify:

> Note that the argument type tuple must be a literal tuple, and not a tuple-valued variable or expression.

For info, I'm in Ubuntu 18.04 and the library has been implemented with

mylib.c:

```
float add3 (float i){
 return i+3;
}
```

mylib.h:

```
#ifndef _MYLIB_H_
#define _MYLIB_H_

extern float get2 ();
extern float add3 (float i);
```

Compilation (gcc):

```
gcc -o mylib.o -c mylib.c
gcc -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.o -lm -fPIC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is the most used pattern:

```
const mylib = joinpath(pwd(), "libmylib.so")
j = ccall((:add3, mylib), Cfloat, (Cfloat,), 2)
```

Note that `pwd` can be a bit more in "flux" than you want for a library path, it is probably better to relate it to the file, e.g.

```
const mylib = joinpath(@__DIR__, "libmylib.so")
```

where `@__DIR__` expands to the directory of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

As often, I found the solution only after posting on SO.. it seems setting the question helps defining better the problem..

Any how, the solution is to first get the function pointer with `cglobal` - where I can use `pwd()` - and then use the `ccall` method with the function pointer:

```
f = cglobal((:add3, "$(pwd())/libmylib.so"))
j = ccall(f, Float32, (Float32,), i)
```

Comment: You might consider using the `joinpath` function when creating an absolute path.